# mysqli prepare not returning results in table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to post each row returned from a prepared statement as an individual table row in custom format - unfortunately I have had poor success with prepared statements in the past and I would like to write this to the current standard-

the below code does not echo any rows onto the table.

Any help is appreciated

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "db");
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE currentemp=1")) {
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
foreach ($result as $row) {
//print data
echo("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='emp". $row['UID'] ."'></td><td>". $row['Fname'] ." ". $row['Lname'] ."</td><td>". $row['hiredate'] ."</td><td>" .$row['certlevel'] ."</td><td>". $row['email'] ."</td><td>". $row['phonenumb'] ."</td></tr>");
}

} else {
echo(" <tr><td colspan=5>No employees found</td></tr>");
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: Use mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); after the for loop. may work for you.

Comment: That did not work - however code fixed to show close in the correct spot

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Is your `$link` handle instantiated properly? It should be created using `mysqli_connect()`, or by creating a valid `mysqli` object.

Comment: well great. instead of using mysqli you can use redbean . its awesome. you may look at it http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-redbean/

Comment: Check the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, it may have resulted in failure.

Comment: Is it possible you mis-spelled `currentemp`? Perhaps it should be `currenttemp`, and you're getting an error which you're not catching? Typically it's a good idea to use `try` and `catch` for stuff like this.

Comment: I realized I was missing $link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "db");

this has corrected part of the problem - it is now finding the row however it is not displaying any of the information did I get the foreach method wrong for this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, according to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` "binds *columns* in the result set to variables."

Also `mysqli_fetch()` only returns one result row. You'll want to loop through the result set with a while loop.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Ddsmp094", "dmt"); 

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT UID, Fname, Lname, hiredate, certlevel, email, phonenumb FROM users WHERE currentemp=1")) {
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $UID, $Fname, $Lname, $hiredate, $certlevel, $email, $phonenumb);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    //print data
    echo("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='emp". $UID ."'></td><td>". $Fname ." ". $Lname ."</td><td>". $hiredate ."</td><td>" .$certlevel ."</td><td>". $email ."</td><td>". $phonenumb ."</td></tr>");
}
} else {
echo(" <tr><td colspan=5>No employees found</td></tr>");
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: I should add, this stuff is much easier to do using [PDO](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).